# Android Photo Camera Upload with Retrofit - ASP.NET MVC Endpoint

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, retrofit

Want to be able to on the fly post an image to my back-end from my Android app. What am I doing wrong here? I keep receiving an internal server error, however I know the endpoint is up and working (able to call it from other clients)

I have an ASP.NET MVC endpoint setup like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostImage(int id, string accessToken, HttpPostedFileBase img)
```

In my Android code, I am using Retrofit with a setup like this:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/endpoint/postimage")
void postImage(
        @Part("id") int id,
        @Part("accessToken") TypedString accessToken,
        @Part("img") TypedByteArray img,
        Callback<Boolean> callback);
```

I have image handling code like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();

//  convert to typed
TypedByteArray typedByteArray = new TypedByteArray("application/octet-stream", bytes);
TypedString str = new TypedString("myString");

RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("https://myendpoint.net").build();

ApiService apiService = adapter.create(ApiService.class);
apiService.PostImage(1492, str, typedByteArray, new Callback<Boolean>() {

    @Override
    public void success(Boolean success, Response response) {

        Boolean test = success;
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        //Log.e("TappedIn", error.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI I've resolved this!

Here is my final code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

  Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
  Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

  ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, out);
  byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

  RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
  .setEndpoint("https://myendpoint.com").build();

  ApiService apiService = adapter.create(ApiService.class);

  TypedByteArray typedByteArray = new TypedByteArray("image/*", bytes) {
    @Override
    public String fileName() {
    return "img.jpg";
    }
  };

TypedString myVar = new TypedString("abc");

apiService.postVenueMenu(venueId, myVar, typedByteArray, new Callback<SuccessDTO>() {

                @Override
                public void success(SuccessDTO success, Response response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```